# IDN domain support in WordPress for Android

Tags: android, wordpress, dns, idn

Any has configured an IDN domain in Wordpress for Android 2.2.7 app?

I've tested with and without punycode notation but doesn't works.

I ever obtain the same error code:

java.net:UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host...

Comment: Tested on 4.4.2 and 2.3.6, no uncaught exceptions, but the connection is not established either, an error pops up. You can try filing a bug at http://android.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: I mean https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android

Answer (score 0):

Punycode is supported in the latest versions of WordPress for Android right now.
A patch for IDN support is in the works, starting here: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/pull/515

Comment: Patch was merged into development version: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android/commit/735074a456ebb33bba5b704fbc08cbc70d5c0c17